# Is a basement ceiling Beam strong enough to hold a swing?

Tags: beam, swing

I'm looking to have someone install a [sensory swing](https://a.co/d/8l1JSqW) for my toddler and although he's little now, I wanted to know what the likely maximum weight for a swing mount would be.

The product has a capacity limit of 200 lbs. But I think that's for the swing itself and not the mount that gets secured to the beam.

I'd like to install it in our family room which is in the basement. Ultimately, I'm just curious how much weight the beam could hold and if it would be safe to use for a teenager/adult sized sensory swing for my son as he grows up.

Comment: We need a lot more info on beam size before any sort of recommendation can be given.  It'd probably be fine for a child, but a lot of it depends on the beam strength itself, which is determined by size, material, span, etc.  Also depends on how you're going to attach it to the beam.  most beams are probably 2x, and screwing into the end likely won't give full design holding strength due to the narrow width and the large screws needed.

Comment: @Milwrdfan How could I figure out what size the beam is? It's not exposed so I can't physically see it. The mount included with the swing uses 2 screws.

Comment: I suspect the beam can hold the weight, if it a straight hang down.  It is how the beam is mounted if it can stand the swinging of the weight.  The beam might just be mounted enough to hold in place with weight holding it down.

Comment: If you can't see it to determine size, type, and span, neither can we. We can't help you. Look around for openings near ductwork, behind unfinished areas, etc., or consult the building plans.

Comment: The area around a furnace is often unfinished; whatever floor joists are visible there are likely to be the same type as those above your family room. If you need help figuring out what kinds of joists or beams you have we could help with that too. In that case consider closing this question, asking a new one for help with determining what sort of structure you have, and then edit and re-open this one to include those details. Small and focused questions are best.

Comment: I doubt a product like that will last to teenage years without replacement from regular wear and tear.  It does seem to limit the swing action to the beam/holder.  The type of beam you have will tell if this is DIY job(including a trip to big boys/girls toy store for new tool) or something you should have a professional do.  Two screws/lag bolts and a new impact wrench is DIY.

Comment: Just to be sure we're on the same page, this beam is a length of sawn lumber, not a truss? And about how old is the house?

Comment: To follow on the comment made by @popham, are talking beam, or joist (a beam typically provides support for a joist)?

Answer (score 1):

The weight limit is 200Kg as it is meant for kids or adults.  House beams are not designed for swinging weights.  While a toddler will probably be okay.  I would not swing an adult off the beam.  If it is attached to plaster ceiling, you may experience cracking.

If you want to swing an adult, you need a steel beam or a discussion with an Engineer.

Answer (score 1):

Since this is the underside of a floor that you walk on, of course the beam can support the weight of a person hanging from it. For any dynamic loading abuse of a swing below the floor, it's pretty easy to imagine worse abuse above the floor from people running, jumping, etc.

Assuming that your beam is a skinny joist, you'll probably want to ponder a bit on how to stiffen the bottom edges of the floor joists against aggressive swinging perpendicular to the joist's length.

If you want a more technical answer, then you'll need to provide technical details.

Answer (score 1):

Summary

That's a very lightweight swing with lightweight mounting hardware.  You don't have to be very sophisticated in how you mount it.  If you do a passable job, the swing itself or its mounting hardware will break before your house.  I would limit that to supervised use by small kids and remove it before they become teens.

More detail

Eventually your child will be a teenager and may have some friends over to play in this thing.  You need to plan for a 200lb adult *dropping* themselves into the swing, swinging enthusiastically, and repeating that hundreds of times.  I don't know how to calculate a dynamic load like that but it's a lot more than 200lb and it may act in almost any direction except up.

Now, this isn't like a lot of other questions about hanging a commercial zip line or a heavy duty swing seat from the ceiling.   This is just a piece of fabric with a (no offence) POS carabiner and a couple of #10 screws.  So I guess we can limit our answers about hanging it from a beam to how to do it in a way that the first thing to fail will be one of the components included with the swing.  You aren't asking "should I buy something stronger?".

If you hang this with a couple of 1-1/2 inch #10 screws as included, you can calculate various limitations of that.  As an example, straight pullout force, have a look here: https://www.engineeringtoolbox.com/wood-screws-allowable-withdrawal-load-d_1815.html   The *example there* is pretty close to your situation!  Look at the pullout force and compare it to what you would imagine is the force of a 200lb adult dropping into the seat.

There's just no way.   Nothing about this will withstand abusive treatment by an adult.  Just limit this to your very small, supervised kids for a few years then get rid of it. Mount it almost any way you want, just not to the drywall!

Comment: That link spits out design values which are predicated on a load duration of 10 years. Wood has a convenient property against impact where it has higher strength for short duration loads. For impact loading you would multiply that link's design values by a 1.6 "load duration factor" to get the 10 minute _design_ (not _ultimate_) strength. See Table 11.3.1 in Chapter 11 of the [NDS](https://awc.org/publications/2018-nds/). The C_D values are found in Chapter 2's Table 2.3.2. The link's equation is under Section 12.2.2 from Chapter 12 if you're interested in the exposition around it.